# Pass new iterated data to props Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-directives

I have one vue component where i fetching data and want to pass with props the iterated 
 result data.  But on newModal component i recived props empty object.
 How can i pass my iterated result  into result object?

```
    <template>
      <div>
            <div
              v-for=" result  in users"
              :key="result.id">
              <div>
                  {{ `${result.user.first_name} ${result.user.last_name}` }}
            </div>
            </div>
            <new-modal v-bind:result="result"/>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import { mapActions } from 'vuex';
    import newModal from './newModal.vue';

    export default {
      components: { newModal },
      data() {
        return {
          users: [],
          result: {},
        };
      },
      async mounted() {
        const { results } = await this.fetchAllUsers();
        this.users = results;
      },

      methods: {
        ...mapActions({
          fetchAllUsers: 'user/fetchAllUsers',
        }),
      },
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: Try rendering `<new-modal/>` inside the `v-for` as explained in below answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Scope of variable: `result` is limited to the loop, `result` won't be accessible outside the loop, instead will throw `reference error`, so, moved `new-modal` inside the loop, also this will enable the component to be rendered for each iteration

```
<div
  v-for="result  in users"
  :key="result.id"
>
  <div>
   {{ `${result.user.first_name} ${result.user.last_name}` }}
  </div>

  <!-- Here -->
  <new-modal v-bind:result="result"/> 
</div>
```